# How to bulk upload documents using Watson Discovery API?

Tags: java, ibm-watson, bulk, watson-discovery

I created one application that inserts or updates documents (depending on whether it is already present or not) in Watson Discovery, using Java.Currently, it is doing the upload one by one, in a for loop.I need to get the same functionality with bulk upload of documents. Is bulk upload feature present in Watson Discovery API? Couldn't find anything in documentation. Could someone point me to any resource on bulk upload of documents?

Answer (score 0):

There is no bulk upload feature in Discovery today, your approach is correct.  Keep in mind you can use many threads though so the upload doesn't need to be one-by-one.

*(I am an IBM Watson Discovery employee)*

Comment: Thanks @catbelly. Can you point me to resources that elaborate about the multi-threading  approach. Also, will this approach save time?